# Why isn't my main function being picked up in my activity file when its declared?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, program-entry-point

I am running a test on an app that someone provided me the code for, and I got everything going except my activity.java, it says R.layout.main and it says main can't be resolved. Its declared, why won't it detect it? Here it is below

Activity.java

```
package magic.test.namespace;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SaytheMagicWordActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/bt_speak" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Speak"
/>
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/tv_result" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text=""
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Is onCreate not being called in SaytheMagicWordActivity?, which would suggest it is missing from the AndroiodManifest.xml OR is R.java missing a public static final class layout?

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file please.

Comment: Check the "Problems" tab on the bottom panel of Eclipse. Anything there?

Comment: remove `import android.R;` and probably do a clean and auto-organize imports(ctrl-shift-o on microsoft windows by default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `import android.R` so it will look for `R.layout.main` in your project instead of `android.R`

Answer (score 0):

The R.java file gets auto-generated in response to modifications in the resource directory.  If your SaytheMagicWordActivity class is showing a compile error resolving R.layout.main, something has screwed up this auto-gen.

You should have a directory in your project should name "res" and it should have a subdirectory "layout" in which there is a main.xml file (res/layout/main.xml).  Do you see this file?  What happens when you change this file?  If you force a recompile of the R.java, you should see the entry for main in there if your directory structure is set up correctly.

Just do the Andriod HelloWorld app and you'll see the basic structure.